# Exception is not caught at Cancelation of Task.Run

Tags: c#, .net, exception, task-parallel-library

I have a class `Worker` which is doing some work (with simulated workload):

```
public class Worker
    { ...

public void DoWork(CancellationToken ct)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
        }
```

Now I want to use this method in a `Task.Run` (from my Windows Forms App,at button-click) which can be cancelled:

```
private CancellationTokenSource _ctSource;

try
            {
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    _worker.DoWork(_ctSource.Token);
                },_ctSource.Token);
            }
            catch (AggregateException aex)
            {
                String g = aex.Message;
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
            {
                String g = ex.Message;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                String g = ex.Message;
            }
```

But when the task is started, I can't cancel it with `_ctSource.Cancel()`;
I get an error in visual studio that the `OperationCanceledException` is not handled!

But I surrounded the Task.Run Call in a try-catch-clause! The Exception which ocurrs in the `Worker` object should thrown up or not? 
What is the problem?

Comment: `OperationHandledException`? Are you sure? I've never heard of such thing.

Comment: I mean OperationCanceledException :-)

Comment: `I get an error in visual studio that the OperationCanceledException is not handled!` Just hit `F5` and ignore it. You won't get it when you run it outside of VS. BTW: You can't catch the task's exception like in your code. You create a task and exit the try block. A `ContinueWith` may help here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Task.Run` call creates the task and then **returns immediately**. It doesn't ever throw. But the task it creates may fail or be canceled **later on**.

You have several solutions here:

- Use `await`:

  ```
  await Task.Run(...)
  ```
- Attach a continuation depending on the failure/cancellation case:

  ```
  var task = Task.Run(...);
  task.ContinueWith(t => ..., TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);
  task.ContinueWith(t => ..., TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
  ```
- Attach a single continuation on failure:

  ```
  Task.Run(...).ContinueWith(t => ..., TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion);
  ```

The solution you can/should use depends on the surrounding code.

Comment: Your solution not worked, i tried await and task.ContinueWith() and still get this error

Comment: This works just fine (and I upvoted it). The problem you have is that you are trying to catch the exception around `Task.Run()` and when the exception rises, the main thread's execution has long passed your `try/catch` block. That's why async tasks don't throw exceptions on the main thread. You need to check for exceptions *after* the code in the task has ran (when the task has ended), either by continuation tasks, or just checking directly on the returned task.

Comment: OK, now i testet it out and put the try-catch-block IN the Task.Run and now it catch!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to new the token
private CancellationTokenSource _ctSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

Why are throwing an expectation in DoWork?
Exception from one thread don't bubble up another thread that started the thread.

[Cancellation in Managed Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If a parallel Task throws an exception it'll return execution and will have it's `Exception` property (as an `AggregateException`, you should check for its `InnerException`) set (and either its `IsCanceled` or `IsFaulted` property set to `true`). Some minimal sample code from a project of mine which escalates the exception to the main thread:

```
  var t = new Task(Initialize);
  t.Start();
  while (!t.IsCompleted && !t.IsFaulted)
  {
    // Do other work in the main thread
  }
  if (t.IsFaulted)
  {
    if (t.Exception != null)
    {
      if(t.Exception.InnerException != null)
        throw t.Exception.InnerException;
    }
    throw new InvalidAsynchronousStateException("Initialization failed for an unknown reason");
  }
```

If you use a `CancellationTokenSource` it should be easy to enhance this to check for `IsCanceled` (instead of `IsFaulted`)

You can also use `Task.Wait()` instead of the `while` loop... in my project and in that precise case it seemed more appropiate to use the while loop, but you need to wait for the `Task` to end in one way or another.

If you use `Task.Run()` you can use a `.ContinueWith(Task)` which will have the original task passed in (where you can check for `IsFaulted` or `IsCanceled`), or have it run only on faulted execution, at your will.